# Heroku and Java: how to set utf-8 as the default encoding postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

How can I config db postgresql is charset utf8 and all tables is utf8?

What is command show charset of postgresql on heroku?

Answer (score 5):

I think UTF8 is the default set by Heroku. Assuming you already have an application and database created, you can confirm via a `psql` session with Heroku, via: `heroku pg:psql -c "show server_encoding"`